# ReactStars component can't set useState - calls TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: reactjs, react-component, rating-system

I'm quite new to React and can't seem to figure out how to resolve this issue. Maybe a stupid question but here it goes.

I'm trying to make a system where each Person can add skills and a rating of those skills. Each array consist of a skill element as a string and a star element as an integer.
I've made some dynamic inputfields with an add and a remove function for more/less inputfields.

For each inputfield I have an onchange function handleChangeInput and this works fine with skills as this is has a property of "name".

Now when trying to fetch the value from ReactStars I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name'). This error is called from the handleChangeInput function. ReactStars doesn't have any property of type either.

How will I be able to fetch the value from ReactStars, if it's even possible? I want to set the useState of inputfields with the values of skill and stars of course.

[Image of the TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km0dT.png).

The component I use is: react-rating-stars-component

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating-stars-component

Hope this explains the problem. Otherwise let me know. Thanks.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const [inputField, setInputField] = useState([{ skill: "", stars: 0 }]);

const handleChangeInput = (index, event) => {
    const values = [...inputField];
    values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setInputField(values);
    setData(values);
  };

const handleAddFields = () => {
    setInputField([...inputField, { skill: "", stars: 0 }]);
  };

  const handleRemoveFields = (index) => {
    const values = [...inputField];
    console.log(inputField.length);
    values.splice(index, 1);
    setInputField(values);
    setData(values);
  };

return(
       <div>
         {inputField?.map((inputField, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={5} md={5}>
                  <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <Form.Control
                      className="mb-3"
                      type="text"
                      id="skill"
                      name="skill"
                      value={inputField?.skill}
                      onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4} md={4}>
                  <Form.Group>
                      <ReactStars
                        type="number"
                        name="stars"
                        count={5}
                        size={24}
                        id="stars"
                        onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                        color="rgba(230, 230, 230, 255)"
                        emptyIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        filledIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        value={inputField.stars}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={3} md={3}>
                  <div className="btn-section">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="round-btn"
                      onClick={() => handleAddFields()}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="round-btn"
                      onClick={() => handleRemoveFields(index)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
);
```

Comment: The error message is telling you "I'm trying to read the key `.name` on something that is `undefined`". You only have 1 place where you're trying to access `.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package passes the new value, not an event containing it.

You can instead simply bind the change handler differently in each case such that the context you need is passed through:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const [inputField, setInputField] = useState([{ skill: "", stars: 0 }]);

const handleChangeInput = (index, name, value) => {
    const values = [...inputField];
    values[index][name] = value;
    setInputField(values);
    setData(values);
  };

const handleAddFields = () => {
    setInputField([...inputField, { skill: "", stars: 0 }]);
  };

  const handleRemoveFields = (index) => {
    const values = [...inputField];
    console.log(inputField.length);
    values.splice(index, 1);
    setInputField(values);
    setData(values);
  };

return(
       <div>
         {inputField?.map((inputField, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={5} md={5}>
                  <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <Form.Control
                      className="mb-3"
                      type="text"
                      id="skill"
                      name="skill"
                      value={inputField?.skill}
                      onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput(index, 'skill', event.target.value)}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4} md={4}>
                  <Form.Group>
                      <ReactStars
                        type="number"
                        name="stars"
                        count={5}
                        size={24}
                        id="stars"
                        onChange={(newValue) => handleChangeInput(index, 'stars', newValue)}
                        color="rgba(230, 230, 230, 255)"
                        emptyIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        filledIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        value={inputField.stars}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={3} md={3}>
                  <div className="btn-section">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="round-btn"
                      onClick={() => handleAddFields()}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="round-btn"
                      onClick={() => handleRemoveFields(index)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I just found a little problem with the code maybe. This function is part of a CRUD person and you should therefore be able to edit the skills. The editSkills component is based in a bootstrap modal. Every time I open the editSkillsModal to edit already stored array of skills the stars in index 0 have been reset to init state (0). - Although I can see that it has successfully stored the data.  Why does it always reset index 0 of stars to init state? Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I'd need to see this edit skills component -- maybe start a new question? One issue you have is you are using `index` as `key` which is a problem since each key would relate to a different entry when you delete one -- which is not allowed. It needs to uniquely identify them and to have it never change throughout the component lifetime. Probably you want to generate a uuid on each entry alongside the `skill` and `stars` property using a UUID library and then use that. This way, the key will be stable.

Comment: I have now made a new question where I display the full code and hope that you'll see if you're able to spot the problem there. Otherwise thanks the tip regarding the UUID cause I think that might be the problem. [Link to new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649626/usestate-resets-to-init-state-in-crud-function-when-edit-reactstars-component) I called the question: useState resets to init state in CRUD function when edit - ReactStars Component