# useState resets to init state in CRUD function when edit - ReactStars Component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, rating-system

I'm trying to make a CRUD person function where each person has an array of skills.
I want a function where you're able to add/edit/remove skills on a given person.
Each array consist of a skill element as a string and a star element as an integer. I've made some dynamic inputfields with an add and a remove function for more/less inputfields in a bootstrap modal.

*The data is fetched from Firebase with a useEffect and set as setData in EditPerson.jsx. No problem here.*

The issue consist of 3 components atm: EditPerson -> ModalEditSkills -> EditSkills. (Please let me know if this is a bad structure).

I'm now able to set the useState of newData in SkillEdit.jsx with the correct data. This makes sure that on EditPerson I'll be able to view the correct data input from given in the EditSkills. Also if I console.log the data in EditSkills I can see that it works like a charm. But when I close the bootstrap modal and open it again the useState in index 0 have been reset to init useState (0).

I can't add images in the text here yet, so here's some links for the images if needed.
The image explains that the console.log tells me that the useState is set correct, but it stills reset the state of index 0 everytime I re-open the modal.

Hope that makes sense otherwise let me know.

[ReactStars-choosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW5SF.png)

[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy2Oz.png)

EditPerson.jsx

```
const EditPerson = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState({});
   const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);
   const { id } = useParams();

   useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "person", id);
        try {
          const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
          setData(docSnap.data());
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
      fetchData().catch(console.error);
    } else {
      setData("");
    }
  }, [id]);

   useEffect(() => {
       if (data) {
         setSkills(data.skills);
       }
     }, [data]);

   const handleSkills = (skill) => {
       setSkills(skill);
     };

   return (
      <div>
         <ModalEditSkills
            handleSkills={handleSkills}
            data={skills}
         />
      </div>
   );
}
```

ModalEditSkills.jsx

```
const ModalEditSkills = ({ data, handleSkills }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setNewData(data);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const handleSubmitSkills = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSkills(newData);
    setShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content_header">
        <div className="content_header_top">
          <div className="header_left">Skills</div>
          <div className="header_right">
            <Button className="round-btn" onClick={handleShow}>
              <i className="fa-solid fa-pencil t-14"></i>
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} size="">
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Edit Person</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <SkillEdit data={data} setNewData={setNewData} />
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Form>
            <Button className="btn-skill-complete" onClick={handleSubmitSkills}>
              Save
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

SkillEdit.jsx

```
const SkillEdit = ({ data, setNewData }) => {
  const [inputField, setInputField] = useState([{ skill: "", stars: 0 }]);

  const handleAddFields = () => {
    setInputField([...inputField, { skill: "", stars: 0 }]);
  };

  const handleRemoveFields = (index) => {
    const values = [...inputField];
    values.splice(index, 1);
    setInputField(values);
    setNewData(values);
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (index, name, value) => {
    const values = [...inputField];
    values[index][name] = value;
    setInputField(values);
    setNewData(values);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const setSkills = () => {
        setInputField(data);
      };
      setSkills();
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <Form>
      <div>
          {inputField?.map((inputField, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={5} md={5}>
                  <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <Form.Control
                      className="mb-3"
                      type="text"
                      id="skill"
                      name="skill"
                      value={inputField?.skill}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleChangeInput(index, "skill", event.target.value)
                      }
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4} md={4}>
                  <div>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <ReactStars
                        type="number"
                        name="stars"
                        count={5}
                        size={24}
                        id="stars"
                        onChange={(newValue) =>
                          handleChangeInput(index, "stars", newValue)
                        }
                        emptyIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        filledIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        value={inputField.stars}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </div>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={3} md={3}>
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => handleAddFields()}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => handleRemoveFields(index)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hmm. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on a codesandbox I whipped up: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-einstein-2yiztf?file=/src/App.js. Can you repro there? Only difference is I replaced the network call with static data for testing.

Comment: One thing I did notice is your modal is showing stale data. Because the open/hide logic doesnt remove the modal component in reality (its hidden with CSS), the state is still there if you change the stars and close the dialogue even if you dont click save. To my surprise, attempting to at effects around `open` to reset it, didnt work.

Comment: Adding a bare minimum of code that reproduces/illustrates the problem will encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took some time for me to work out. I had trouble reproducing and still do, but I noticed a lot of odd behaviour around the stars. In the end, I've figured out it's probably [this bug](https://github.com/n49/react-stars/issues/68) in the `react-stars` package.

Unfortunately, the `value` prop does not actually control the value after the initial render. So it's like an [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) component. The library therefore, is poor. It hasn't been committed to for 4 years. Usually, if a component is uncontrolled, the developer calls the prop `initialValue` or `defaultValue` instead of `value`, which usually implies the component is *controlled*. Here, the author has made a mistake. Regardless, in your case, you need *controlled* mode.

It's possible there's another bug interacting. But I'd start by replacing react-stars as not being able to have controlled mode is extremely poor and it makes it very hard to see the wood through the trees. There is a "solution" in the GitHub thread but it's a massive hack -- it's using the special `key` property to remount it every time the value changes.

I went looking for an alternative and much to my surprise a lot of the other libraries are also uncontrolled -- which really sucks. What you could do instead of the hack in the GitHub issue, is make it so the dialog is unmounted when `open` is `false`. This would mean each time the dialog opens it resets the value back to that which is held in the parent state. See my bottom code for that solution.

There's good options though [here](https://rsuitejs.com/components/rate/) and [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-rating/) but they are part of larger design systems, and it's probably overkill to bring in a whole other design system when you have committed to bootstrap. Depending on how early you are in your project though, I'd seriously consider switching to something like MUI. Personal opinion territory, but Bootstrap is pretty outdated and the React wrapper and associated community, plus diversity of components, is much smaller. It shows that `react-bootstrap` is a wrapper on top of old school global CSS files as opposed to `material-ui` which was built from the ground up in React and has a React based CSS-in-JS solution. When people first start learning React, they often slip into bootstrap because it's what they know from non-React dev -- but using a framework like React moves the needle and trade-offs.

It's not your problem here, but I feel the need to say it :D. At the same time I'd say don't always take a random internet strangers recommendation and refactor for nothing -- you should research it.

A few other important notes:

- If `id` is not set, you set `data` to an empty string. If that case ever happened for real, your code would error since accessing `data.skills` would result in `undefined`. I would argue that you shouldn't even need to handle this case, since your router setup should be such that there is no mapping between this component and a route without an id. Make sure on your router config the `id` param is non-optional.
- You are copying `data.skills` into a new state item called `skills`. It's not a bug *per se* but it is a code smell as it's not actually necessary. Why not edit the data in the `data` state directly? Copying state that is fundamentally the same is usually an anti-pattern as you can fall into traps where you are trying to keep 2 bits of state in sync that are supposed to be the same. I think it's OK where you do it further down as I believe you are copying it because you want that state not to be committed further up until the user clicks save -- which means it's actually fundamentally different state at given times. But that doesn't apply to the top level `data` vs `skills` one. Actually, I think the `inputField` state is also not needed since your "staged" state is held by the parent `ModalEditSkills` in `newData`. You could instead get rid of this `inputField` state and have `handleChangeInput`, `handleAddFields` and `handleRemoveFields` call up into `ModalEditSkills` to patch `newData` directly. Then pass that down. This will greatly reduce the surface area for bugs and remove unnecessary effects in `SkillEdit`.
- You are often passing props called `set[Something]`. Generally, in react, you want to keep to the naming convention of user triggered events beginning with `on`. The trouble with the former, is it implies that the user action does a certain thing, which makes the component look like it's less reusable in other contexts (even though it's the same behaviour really, it's just incorrect naming).
- When setting a state item that's derived partly from its previous value, you should use the callback pattern of `setState` (which is passed the current value) instead of referencing the state value returned from `useState`. This avoids bugs to do with accidentally getting a stale value when you update state in a loop or something. React doesn't actually update the value of the state immediately, it gets flushed at the end of the call stack. Using the previous value callback gets around this. Not a problem that will show up in your code, just good practice that you should get in the habit of.
- There's a bug where you need to reset the form data back to the data stored in the top component when it opens/closes because currently if you make a change and close dialogue, without clicking save, it's still there next time you open it. It's not actually saved to the parent state, it's just hanging around in the background (hidden). It's weird UX so I've fixed by adding `show` to the effect that resets the `newData` state. If you really wanted it how it was though you can just remove that again from the deps array.
- There was also a bug in the way you were patching the state when editing an existing skill. Even though you cloned the skills array by spreading a new one, this only does a shallow clone. The object you spread into the array are the same (as in literally, the same object reference) as the original ones. This meant you were mutating the `data` prop which is not allowed in react. I've changed to `Object.assign` to make sure it's a proper edited clone. The way this works if everything gets merged from right to left. So by the first param being `{}`, you start with a brand new object and then you load int the old + new data into it. Libraries like Immer make this easier, you might want to look into it.
- I haven't fixed this one as it's kind of up to you but if you were on slow network, there would be a period where you could confuse the user since the data hasn't come back yet but they can open the dialogue and see no skills. You might want to handle that case by showing a loading display instead of the rest of the app whilst it's in flight. You could make the default state of the top level `data` state `null` and then only populate it when the request comes back like you do now. Then in the top level render you'd check for `null` and return some loading display instead of `ModalEditSkills`. Similar stuff would happen if the network errored. You might also want to have some new state that says if an error happened (instead of just logging), and check that as well and display the error page.

Here's the code with my proposed changes (minus the library change, you'd still need to do that if you cared enough).

And here's a code sandbox with it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-meadow-3ru2nq?file=/src/App.js (I replaced the network call with static data for testing, and I don't have your icons).

```
const EditPerson = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState({skills: []});
   const { id } = useParams();

   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "person", id);
        try {
          const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
          setData(docSnap.data());
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
      fetchData().catch(console.error);
  }, []);

   const handleSkillsChanged = (skills) => {
       setData(data => ({...data, skills}));
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <ModalEditSkills
            onSkillsChanged={handleSkillsChanged}
            data={data.skills}
         />
      </div>
   );
}
```

```
const ModalEditSkills = ({ data, onSkillsChanged}) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
     setNewData(data);
  }, [data, show]);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const handleSkillChange = (index, name, value) => {
    setNewData(prevValues => {
        const newValues = [...prevValues]
        newValues[index] = Object.assign({}, newValues[index], { [name]: value });
        return newValues
    });
  }

  const handleSkillAdded = () => {
    setNewData(prevValues => [...prevValues, { skill: "", stars: 0 }]);
  }  

  const handleSkillRemoved = (index) => {
    setNewData(prevValues => {
          const newValues = [...prevValues];
          newValues.splice(index, 1);
          return newValues
    });
  }  

  const handleSubmitSkills = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSkillsChanged(newData);
    setShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content_header">
        <div className="content_header_top">
          <div className="header_left">Skills</div>
          <div className="header_right">
            <Button className="round-btn" onClick={handleShow}>
              <i className="fa-solid fa-pencil t-14"></i>
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {show && (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} size="">
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Edit Person</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <SkillEdit
              data={newData}
              onSkillChanged={handleSkillChange}
              onSkillAdded={handleSkillAdded}
              onSkillRemoved={handleSkillRemoved}
            />
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Form>
              <Button
                className="btn-skill-complete"
                onClick={handleSubmitSkills}
              >
                Save
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const SkillEdit = ({ data, onSkillChanged, onSkillRemoved, onSkillAdded}) => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <div>
          {data?.map((inputField, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={5} md={5}>
                  <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <Form.Control
                      className="mb-3"
                      type="text"
                      id="skill"
                      name="skill"
                      value={inputField?.skill}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        onSkillChanged(index, "skill", event.target.value)
                      }
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4} md={4}>
                  <div>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <ReactStars
                        type="number"
                        name="stars"
                        count={5}
                        size={24}
                        id="stars"
                        onChange={(newValue) =>
                          onSkillChanged(index, "stars", newValue)
                        }}
                        emptyIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        filledIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-star"></i>}
                        value={inputField.stars}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </div>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={3} md={3}>
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={onSkillAdded}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => onSkillRemoved(index)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this long and very useful answer. As I'm in the beginning of my "react journey" this answer helpes me a lot. I added the changes to my code and it worked, but I only see one "error" which is only for the purpose of my system. If the data.skills is 0 (a user as deleted all skills) there will not be gereratet any inputfields ,and I'm not able to use the handleSkillAdded as this requires a prevValue. I guess that I need to create a seperat method for this? I will also try to implement the loading in the ModalEditSkills as you suggested.

Comment: I noticed that the problem is that if I use this form for to create a new person (therefore no id) I will not be able to use the function onSkillAdded. I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: prevValues is not iterable. But I fixed this issue with just setting a init state to a empty string. Doesn't know if this is the right way to do it, but it worked ;)  <ModalEditSkills onSkillsChanged={handleSkillsChanged} data={data.skills || ""} />

Comment: Hmm thats interesting. Im guessing where there are no skills coming back from the external service (whatever getDoc does), that it returns something unexpected (probably an object with the skills key set to null or something). Instead of `data.skills || "` you want `data.skills ?? []` because you want it to be consistently an array.

Comment: Okay that's useful to know because I used String in most cases also with arrays. It all work like a charm now. I can't seem to find any issues anymore. Thanks a lot again, you're a champ! :)